# Enabling APC causes internal server error

Tags: php, centos, fastcgi

After installing and enabling APC 3.1.9 (Alternate PHP Cache), using `pecl`, i ran into an internal server error. I checked my error logs, and this is what shows up.

**Error Logs:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mkstemp on /tmp/apc.efdb4d failed: in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Jul 06 23:47:41 2011] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper(22397) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

Instead of adding the APC extension to my `php.ini` file, i created an `apc.ini` file in `/etc/php.d/`, here's my current APC configuration

**apc.ini configuration:**

```
; /etc/php.d/apc.ini

extension = apc.so

apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 128M
apc.optimization = 0
apc.num_files_hint = 4096
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.gc_ttl = 0
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.filters = ""
apc.mmap_file_mask = "/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.enable_cli = 0
apc.max_file_size = 10M
apc.stat = 1
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.report_autofilter = 0
apc.include_once_override = 0
;apc.rfc1867 = 0
;apc.rfc1867_prefix = "upload_"
;apc.rfc1867_name = "APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS"
;apc.rfc1867_freq = 0
apc.localcache = 0
apc.localcache.size = 512
apc.coredump_unmap = 0
apc.stat_ctime = 0
```

Even after disabling APC, i ran into another error while trying to log in to Plesk CP:

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_6d7_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)
```

I fixed the above problem by restarting my container through Plesk's Power Panel. I think it had to with changing `/tmp` to `exec` using `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` to solve permission errors during the APC installation through `pecl`. After the installation was done, I returned `/tmp` back to `noexec`. The gist of these steps can be found [here](http://johnmercer.org/my-epic-battle-to-install-apc/).

The first error still remains unsolved.

**I'm Currently running on:**

- CentOS 5.6
- PHP 5.3.5
- FastCGI
- Installed APC 3.1.9

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Is it because im using the lastest version of APC? or the `apc.ini` config? Does it matter where i enabled the apc extension? i.e. `/etc/php.ini` versus `/etc/php.d/apc.ini`

How about FastCGI and APC compability issues?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no problem with your apc.ini file - I have the exact same setup (CentOS/PHP 5.3.6/FastCGI/APC 3.1.6) and your apc.ini file worked without issue. I might guess that you have a permissions problem on your /tmp directory - try setting it to 0777 to diagnose; if that fixes it, either change the mmap path or narrow down the permissions to something acceptable.

Comment: @cyberx86 Thanks a lot buddy. I ended up solving the problem using your advice. The problem was on multiple fronts. The `apc.ini` file was supplemented by w3 total cache's plugin in its `ini` folder. It was owned by my ftp user (it was `cp`-ed directly from there to `/etc/php.d/`), so i just changed it to `root/root`, and the `/tmp` folder had restrictive permissions, so i loosened it up a little bit. Answer the question, so i can give you credit. Thanks again.

Comment: Give it to @Aleksey Korzun - he has essentially the same thing, just approached differently, and posted it before I did (which is why I didn't post mine as an answer - didn't seem right). Glad it worked out - thanks for thought.

Comment: for sure @cyberx86. by the way, whats considered a secure set of permissions for the `/tmp` folder, and what would be an alternative to it?

Comment: Ideally if you can avoid execution permissions that is a good. Usually tmp is owned by root - and you will have other 'users' writing there - which means at least 0666 is common. Most linux distros have 0777 drwxrwxrwt (t=only user can delete). Make it as tight as possible - if you don't have any users writing to tmp, try a 0664 or even a 0644, but I don't think most things will work with those.

Comment: thanks @cyberx86. I'll look into it more and see what I can get away with. I cant believe how much of an impact opcode caching has on a website. Onload times are reduced 50-70%.

Comment: Depending on the type of site, a disk cache can be even more effective - either generating and serving static pages, or using a caching proxy (e.g. nginx's proxy_cache or squid); you may also consider looking into memcached. (And of course, check out the apc.php file that shows which pages get the most caching, etc - potentially useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have open_dir restrictions in effect? If this is on user account I would set APC's tmp directory relative to users home directory with proper permissions.

Comment: thanks for looking out. pretty much what @cyberx86 stated.

Comment: Damn it @cyberx86! :)